# How to destructure multiple properties from a struct in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have one struct that I would like to destructure couple of properties from it. I can use the following code. However, how can I combine `let make, let model, let year` into one line?

```
struct Car {
    let make: String
    let model: String
    let year: Int
}

struct PersonCar {
    let auto: Car
    let isUsed: Bool
}

let car = PersonCar(auto: Car(make: "Subaru", model: "Outback", year: 2017), isUsed: false)
let isUsed = car.isUsed
let carDetail = car.auto
let {make, model , year} = carDetail /// error: cannot assign to immutable expression of type 
// let make = carDetail.make
// let model = carDetail.model
// let year = carDetail.year
print(car)
print(make)
print(model)
print(year)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no "destructuring" syntax in Swift like there is in Scala for example. Swift structs don't work that way. It opens up a lot of tricky corner cases, and so far the Swift team hasn't chosen to open that can of worms. The most salient question is how this should handle computed properties (including computed properties that are added in an extension), which generally are considered an implementation detail that should be changeable without breaking calling code. Also how this should handle callers at different access levels? Should `private` properties be part of the destructure and to which callers? These are not insurmountable problems. Other languages have chosen answers. But they haven't risen to the level to be designed and solved for Swift. If you have good ideas here, I expect the Swift forums would be a good place to read and contribute.

Of course there are several ways to put it on one line. The most obvious is:

```
let (make, model, year) = (carDetail.make, cardDetail.model, carDetail.year)
```

But there is little reason to go down this road.

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to do this, you could do this following:

```
let (make, model, year) = (car.auto.make, car.auto.model, car.auto.year)
```

Comment: This is already in the previous answer.

Comment: When I started writing my answer, the other answer was not yet visible.